# can not sign in online accounts with facebook

Tags: firefox, empathy, facebook

I tried to enter a new facebook account via gnome-control-center's "Online Accounts" but it doesn't work. When I click facebook, it shows a rotating icon then firefox opens and opens a page where facebook asks me my email address and password then nothing. Nothing happends. It just redirected to this Web address:

```
https://www.facebook.com/connect/blank.html#_=_
```

It and has these words:

> Success
>
> **SECURITY WARNING** : Please treat the URL above as you would your password and do not share it with anyone.

Have also tried upgrading packages but still it doesn't work.

I am also using x86 version of ubuntu raring and also the problem doesn't appear on the x86_64 version of ubuntu raring.

Update: After updating my x86_64 installation of ubuntu raring the problem appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a Workaround. Check this : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/account-plugins/+bug/1180297/comments/4.

Edit /usr/share/accounts/providers/facebook.provider

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/accounts/providers/facebook.provider
```

Put this **under** line 13,

```
<setting name="AllowedSchemes" type="as">['https','http']</setting>
```

Example:

This is the **original** /usr/share/accounts/providers/facebook.provider:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<provider id="facebook">
   <name>Facebook</name>
  <icon>facebook</icon>
  <translations>account-plugins</translations>
  <domains>.*facebook\.com</domains>
  <plugin>generic-oauth</plugin>
  <template>
    <group name="auth">
      <setting name="method">oauth2</setting>
      <setting name="mechanism">user_agent</setting>
      <group name="oauth2">
        <group name="user_agent">        
          <setting name="Host">www.facebook.com</setting>
          <setting name="AuthPath">/dialog/oauth</setting>
          <setting name="RedirectUri">https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html</setting>
          <setting name="Display">popup</setting>
          <setting type="as" name="Scope">['publish_stream','read_stream','status_update','user_photos','friends_photos','xmpp_login']</setting>
          <setting name="ClientId">302061903208115</setting>
        </group>
      </group>
    </group>
  </template>
</provider>
```

This is the **modified** /usr/share/accounts/providers/facebook.provider:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<provider id="facebook">
   <name>Facebook</name>
  <icon>facebook</icon>
  <translations>account-plugins</translations>
  <domains>.*facebook\.com</domains>
  <plugin>generic-oauth</plugin>
  <template>
    <group name="auth">
      <setting name="method">oauth2</setting>
      <setting name="mechanism">user_agent</setting>
      <group name="oauth2">
        <group name="user_agent">      
+         <setting name="AllowedSchemes" type="as">['https','http']</setting>  
          <setting name="Host">www.facebook.com</setting>
          <setting name="AuthPath">/dialog/oauth</setting>
          <setting name="RedirectUri">https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html</setting>
          <setting name="Display">popup</setting>
          <setting type="as" name="Scope">['publish_stream','read_stream','status_update','user_photos','friends_photos','xmpp_login']</setting>
          <setting name="ClientId">302061903208115</setting>
        </group>
      </group>
    </group>
  </template>
</provider>
```

Note:  however that this exposes your desktop to some security risks, so please use it only if you are connected to a trusted network. -- [Alberto Mardegan (mardy)](https://launchpad.net/~mardy)

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center-signon/+bug/1180297

Update: Seems that this bug is fixed on the quantal-proposed and raring-proposed. The package is `account-plugin-facebook` and its version is `0.10bzr13.03.26-0ubuntu1.1`

Comment: This doesn't work, now I can't open Online Account.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked for me, with Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit.

Comment: Can we perhaps **reduce security risks** a little bit if we only include **'https'** and leave out **'http'** in this line to be inserted?

Comment: I do not know @Sadi because I am not a developer or a coder. I just  found this comment while searching the net. Sorry... still at 14